# pagination not working when isset is used

Tags: php, pagination

my code is as follows

```
  if(isset($_POST['find_x']) || isset($_POST['find_y'])){ ?>

<table style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
 <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><td colspan="11" align="left">Total Repairs: <? $count=mysql_num_rows($result); echo "<b style='color:#F00;'>".$count."</b>"; ?></td></tr>
    <tr  class="tableDetail" style="background-image:url(../images/tblHeaderBack.jpg);"  >
    <td  align="center">Customer Name</td>
    <td  align="center">Serial #</td>
    <td align="center">Ack No</td>
    <td align="center">RAF Date</td>
    <td align="center">Phone No</td>
    <td align="center">Email</td>
    <td align="center">Product Details</td>
    <td align="center">Repair Status</td>
    <td align="center">Location Name</td>
    <td align="center">Physical Location</td>
    <td align="center">Aging</td>
    <td align="center">Assigned To</td>
    <td align="center">Created By</td>
    </tr>

<?

    $adjacents = 1;

    /* 
       First get total number of rows in data table. 
       If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
    */
    $query = "select count(*) as num from tblRepairQueue where repairStatus!='Closed and Complete' ";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "lookup1.php";    //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit =10;                                 //how many items to show per page
    $page = $_POST['page'];

    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */

    $sql = "select *  from tblRepairQueue where repairStatus!='Closed and Complete'  order by savedAt DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">previous</span>";   

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next </a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next </span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        { ?>
<tr id="<?php $row['serialNo'] ?>" align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#FFF">
    <td ><?=$row['customerName']?></td>
    <td ><?=$row['serialNo']?></td>
    <td ><?=$row['ackNo']?></td>
    <td ><?=$row['savedAt']?></td>
    <td ><?=$details['phoneNo']?></td>
     <td ><?=$details['emailId']?></td>
    <td ><?=$row['productDescription']?></td>
     <td nowrap="nowrap"><?=$row['repairStatus']?></td>
      <td ><?=$row['location']?></td>
      <td ><?=$row['phyLocation']?></td>
       <td ><? echo "<b>".$days."</b><span style='color:#F00'>d</span>&nbsp;<b>".$hours."</b><span style='color:#F00'>hr</span>&nbsp;<b>".$mins."</b><span style='color:#F00'>m</span>";?></td>
       <td ><?=$row['assignedTo']?></td>
        <td ><?=$row['createdUser']?></td>
    </tr>

    <? } ?>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="9"><?=$pagination?>    </td></tr>
</table>

<? }
  ?>
```

when i click on find button pagination comes only for first page but if i click on next page or any numbers its not working.pagination not working if i click on next button..can anyone help me in finding the solution

Comment: It is good you paste complete code. But it would be better if you specify particular block of code. I am not able to find single isset in your code

Comment: @Roopendra i pasted only required part of code..the code is still bigger

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: not working means as soon as u load test1.php file u get 10 rows with pagination which is good but when u click on next button in pagination the page does not load anything

Comment: your count and your row getting query are different - one is using `!=` the other is using `=`. so fix that and then check your results. edit: I expect just removing the negation on the second query will give you the exact results your were expecting.

Comment: i corrected it...but also its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for POST method variables in:

```
if(isset($_POST['find_x']) || isset($_POST['find_y'])){ ?>
```

but you use GET methods in pagination, so post variables aren't available and that clause is always false.

Change your search to use $_GET params. So in your search form:

```
<form method="get" action="lookup1.php">
```

then check for get variables instead of post:

```
$find_x = (isset($_GET['find_x']) ? $_GET['find_x'] : '');
$find_y = (isset($_GET['find_y']) ? $_GET['find_y'] : '');
```

and add find_x and find_y to your pagination links like:

```
"<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&find_x=$find_x\">$counter</a>"
```

Comment: i used POST methods inside pagination..my guess is becuase of isset its not working..

Comment: You can't set post variables with anchor links. You have to use forms to post data. I can't see any forms in your code. It works first time because you are posting data from some kind of form and then another of those two variables are available.

Comment: m using form only with method post

Comment: yeah, so when you click any of those links (in pagination) THERE WILL BE NO POST PARAMETERS, isset($_POST[any]) IS ALWAYS EMPTY = FALSE AND YOU CAN'T SEE ANYTHING.. TRY TO UNDERSTAND WHAT I AM SAYING.

Comment: ya i understand ...so is there any alternative..so that when i click on search button i should get the results

Comment: @Hardy when i add if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { line and do my paging, pages are not getting displayed. How to solve this. I need paging inside submit button